# Convert String[*,*] into int[*,*] in C# winform application

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello everyone I am new to programming in c#, what I am going to do is that I want to convert the 2D string array to 2D integer array, the reason for this conversion is that I want to pass that integer array to another method for some calculation. Thanks in advance for helping.

```
        public void Matrix()
        {
            int a = int.Parse(txtRowA.Text);
            int b = int.Parse(txtColA.Text);


            Random rnd = new Random();
            int[,] matrixA = new int[a, b];

            string matrixString = "";
            
            for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
                {
                    matrixA[i, j] = rnd.Next(1, 100);

                    matrixString += matrixA[i, j];
                    matrixString += "    ";

                   
                }
                matrixString += Environment.NewLine;
            }

            

            txtA.Text = matrixString;
            txtA.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;


        }
```

Comment: I don't understand. At all. In your code, you don't have a `string[,]` array anywhere. But you already got the `int[,]` array. What gives...? (o.O)?

Comment: the array stored in matrixString is in string form, when I try to pass it to another method as a argument, I get the error that 'String cannot be convert to int[,]' , as I have used int[,] as a parameter in that method. I just need to convert back the matrix which is stored in string form to int .

Comment: (1/2) So, even though you talk about 2D string array in both the title and body of your question, your question is actually not related to some 2D string array. In the future, please be more careful in how you craft your questions, because help/suggestions/advice can only be as good as the question is. But back to the topic. You don't need to convert back the matrix, because you already have it in `int[,]` array form.

Comment: (2/2) Instead of trying to crudely hack around with some string composing and deconstruction, what you really need is to come up with a design of your classes and logic that will allow you to share that `int[,]` between the concerned parts/classes of your app. It's not a matter of how you write this or that code line or call some function, it's a matter of how you design and structure your classes and the relationships between them. Thus, i would suggest to do just that instead of seeking some advice for what is essentially nothing more than a hack to work around flaws in your program design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is actually pretty close. Try this:

```
private Random rnd = new Random();

public int[,] Matrix(int a, int b)
{
    int[,] matrixA = new int[a, b];
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
        {
            matrixA[i, j] = rnd.Next(1, 100);
        }
    }
    return matrixA;
}
```

What you have there is a function that does not rely on any WinForms controls and will produce your `int[,]` quickly and efficiently.

Let the calling code work with the WinForms controls:

```
int a = int.Parse(txtRowA.Text);
int b = int.Parse(txtColA.Text);
int[,] matrix = Matrix(a, b);
```

Now you can pass the matrix to anything that requires an `int[,]`.

If you need to display the matrix then create a separate function for that:

```
public string MatrixToString(int[,] matrix)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new();
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        string line = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            line += $"{matrix[i, j]}    ";
        }
        sb.AppendLine(line.Trim());
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Your calling code would look like this:

```
int a = int.Parse(txtRowA.Text);
int b = int.Parse(txtColA.Text);
int[,] matrix = Matrix(a, b);
UseTheMatrix(matrix);
txtA.Text = MatrixToString(matrix);
txtA.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
```

A sample run produces:

[image: matrix]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!! This is exactly what I wanted to do.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **List** as a helper to store the elements of the array extracted from the string, but first I replaced the SPACE between elements in your string with a special character '|' as a separator to make it easier to extract the numbers from the string.

you can do somthing like this:

```
public static int[,] ConvertToInt(string matrix)
    {
        List<List<int>> initial = new List<List<int>>();

        int lineNumber          = 0;
        int currenctIndex       = 0;
        int lastIndex           = 0;
        int digitCount          = 0;

        initial.Add(new List<int>());

        foreach (char myChar in matrix.ToCharArray())
        {

            if (myChar == '|')
            {
                
                initial[lineNumber].Add(int.Parse(matrix.Substring(lastIndex, digitCount)));
                lastIndex  = currenctIndex+1;
                digitCount = 0;
            }
            else
                digitCount++;

            if (myChar == '\n')
            {
                lineNumber++;
                if(currenctIndex < matrix.Length-1)
                    initial.Add(new List<int>());
            }

            currenctIndex++;
            
        }

        int[,] myInt = new int[initial.Count, initial[0].Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < initial.Count; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < initial[i].Count; j++)
                myInt[i, j] = initial[i][j];

        return myInt;
    }
```

Comment: Did you test this before posting?